# Data don't insert into an array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, inheritance

I have my class *CompressionAlgorithm* from which classes *RLE* and *MTF* inherits. I made an array to which I am trying to add these child classes but only first class gets added.

```
int const size = 2;
CompressionAlgorithm * CA[size];
CA[0] = new RLE();
CA[1] = new MTF();
```

Both RLE and MTF get initialized but when I am trying to print their name using *printall* method MTF doesn't get any info printed on console or I am getting an error saying std::bad_alloc.

```
Print p;
p.printall(*CA, (size));
void Print::printall(CompressionAlgorithm *ca, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
       cout << i+1 << " for ";
       cout << ca[i].GetName();
       cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Why not simply using a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CompressionAlgorithm >> CA(size);` or at least a `std::array<std::unique_ptr<CompressionAlgorithm >,2> CA;` instead? Avoid using `new` and raw c-style arrays in c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need make function to accept array of pointers not just a pointer:

`void Print::printall(CompressionAlgorithm *ca[], int size)`

and whil calling you need to call like this:

`p.printall(CA, (size));`

Comment: and in the end change `cout << ca[i].GetName();` to `cout << ca[i]->GetName();` Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to dereference the pointer when passing it to the function; doing so only passes the first element. Additionally the function signature needs to accept an array of pointers, which is what you have.

Answer (score 0):

instead of calling *ca in the printall() call only ca as calling *ca only accesses the first element of the array when not in a loop.